Entropy in a thermally isolated system
In page 141 of the book "Concepts in thermal physics" it is said that for a thermally isolated, the change in entropy is bigger or equal to 0 since $dQ=0$.
But since the system is thermally isolated, doesn't that also mean that dQ rev is 0 (also meaning change in entropy to be 0), therefore just saying that 0=0, not actually showing how entropy is increasing or staying the same?

Could you cite the book that you are talking about?

Concepts in Thermal Physics by Blundell, page 141


In page 141 of the book "concepts of thermal" it is said that for a
thermally isolated, the change in entropy is bigger or equal to 0
since $dQ=0$.

There's only two ways that the entropy of a system can change.
One is the transfer of entropy into or out of the system by means of heat. If the system is thermally isolated, there can be no heat transfer, and therefore the entropy of the system can neither increase nor increase by means of heat.
The second way the entropy of the system can change is by means of an irreversible process. That change is called entropy generation and is always positive. So if a system is thermally isolated its entropy can only stay the same, for a reversible process, or increase increase due to an irreversible process. For a thermally isolated system the irreversible process is an irreversible adiabatic process (since irreversible heat transfer is not possible for a thermally isolated system.)
That is what your book is saying.

But since the system is thermally isolated, doesn't that also mean
that dQ rev is 0 (also meaning change in entropy to be 0), therefore
just saying that 0=0, not actually showing how entropy is increasing
or staying the same?

Although change is defined for a reversible transfer of heat, entropy generation can occur without heat transfer. Examples are irreversible adiabatic processes such as the free expansion of a gas inside a rigid insulted vessel (Joule expansion), and the rapid expansion of a gas against a piston in an insulated piston/cylinder (irreversible expansion work). Neither involves heat, but both generate entropy.
To determine the generated entropy you can replace the actual irreversible process with any convenient reversible process involving heat transfer that connects the same two equilibrium states, and apply the Clausius definition of entropy (see link provided by @Roger V.). The reversible process chosen need not bear any resemblance to the actual process. This can be done because entropy is a state property independent of the path.
For a tutorial on how to calculate the entropy change, see https://www.physicsforums.com/insights/grandpa-chets-entropy-recipe/
Hope this helps.

I suspect that what poses a problem here is the Clausius definition of entropy in terms of heat.

@RogerV. yeah, the OP may not realize that while entropy is defined for a reversible transfer of heat, entropy generation can occur without heat. I'll update my answer. Thanks.

But aren't adiabatic processes also isentropic? And even then, my problem is that in the book, they use Clausius inequality to then show that the change in entropy is either bigger or the same as dQ/T for an irreversible process.

@AankNum only reversible adiabatic processes are isentropic (no change in entropy). Irreversible adiabatic processes generate entropy. As far as your book goes I’ll have to take a look at it in context

".. an irreversible process. But then a thermally isolated system is considered and as dQ=0, the change in entropy would be bigger or equal to 0. The problem is that entropy is defined as dQ (rev) /T, and since for a thermally isolated system dQ(rev)=0=dQ, it does not show that it is actually bigger or equal to 0 but rather saying that 0=0. It might just have been said in a confusing way, but it is just not making sense

@AankNum it can be confusing. Did you look at the link I gave you at the end of my answer?  It is an excellent tutorial and should clarify things for you
